# no such column: todoApp_todolist.category_id

Tags: django

from django.db import models

## Create your models here.

from django.utils import timezone

class Category((models.Model)):

```
name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Meta:

    verbose_name=("Category")

    verbose_name_plural=("Categories")

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
```

class TodoList(models.Model):

```
title=models.CharField(max_length=250)

content=models.TextField(blank=True)

created=models.DateField(default=timezone.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d"))   

# due_date=models.DateField(default=timezone.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d"))


category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Meta:
    ordering=["-created"]     

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes i makemigrstions and migrate butt still issue.

Comment: It is not a recommended method BUT delete all the files in migrations folder except `init.py` AND then `make migrations again` .

Comment: @ziaullah Try `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>` where `<appname>` is the name of the app in which this model is present.